# Frontend displays wrong number digits

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, display

How do I change the default precision in Mathematica?

Somehow the setting has been changed to 1 digit, so if I type

```
Timing[...]
```

I get

> {1., ...}

which is not very enlightening. Similarly,

```
N[Pi]
```

is

> 3.

Compare Mathematica's documentation for [Numerical Precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html) which says of the above command "In standard output form, Mathematica prints a number like this to six digits." So something isn't right with my setup.

I read the guide to numerical precision but it didn't appear to address this issue.

Note that I do *not* want to change `WorkingPrecision` or `PrecisionGoal` on a particular function,but just change the default setting. (Of course I'll have to adjust these in some cases, but I just want to have a sensible starting point.)

Comment: I have marked this as "already has an answer here:" because I think it has.  If `PrintPrecision` does not solve your problem @comment me or flag this post for moderator attention.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks. Actually this doesn't address my problem. For example, the documentation says of `N[Pi]` "In standard output form, Mathematica prints a number like this to six digits." But I get 0, and I don't want to have to append `PrintPrecision` to every command I run. (I'm not even sure if it applies to a command like `Timing` in any case.)

Comment: Did you change any options under Preferences->Appearance->Numbers->Formatting? Are you working on a fresh kernel? Your question title may be misleading if your display is somehow messed up.

Comment: @YvesKlett: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the correct answer is in the linked thread, but the accepted one does not adress the issue here... best practice?

Comment: @YvesKlett Nothing can be done about it. OPs are free to choose whichever answer they like best. The votes tell that Rolf's answer is more useful... In such cases, I suggest just leaving the OP of the duplicate a comment pointing to the most useful answer.

Comment: @YvesKlett: I don't know the best practice here. I'm satisfied with any outcome, though I would prefer to credit you with the answer. (My troubles may not be over: soon after changing the setting it reset itself back to 1. I changed it back a second time and haven't had problems yet, but we'll see if it sticks when I restart.)

Comment: I guess Rolf´s and Mr. Wizard´s answer in the linked thread are on spot, no worries about the rep. Good luck with your prefs :D